# pgfplots: Splitting xlabel on two lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to split xlabel into lines. My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
       % xlabel = Temp, $N$ \newline Slice at X
        xlabel = Temp $N$ \newline Slice at X        
        , ylabel = $P$
        , zlabel = Response
        , xmin = -1
        , xmax = 1
        , ymin = -1
        , ymax = 1
        %, x dir = reverse
        , view={-40}{30}]
   \addplot3
   [
    surf
   ,  faceted color=blue
   , samples  = 15
   , domain   = -1:1
   , y domain = -1:1
   ]
    {56+ 1* x + 2* y + 3*x*y};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder how to split xlabel into two lines and also how to put comma (,) in the xlabel. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xlabel` is printed as node. So you can set a specific text width. This allows line breaks. The modification can be done by the option `xlabel style`. An example is shown in the documentation on page 173:

```
xlabel style={align=right,text width=3cm}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
       % xlabel = Temp, $N$ \newline Slice at X
        xlabel style={draw,rectangle,align=left,text width=2cm},
        xlabel = Temp $N$ \newline Slice at X        
        , ylabel = $P$
        , zlabel = Response
        , xmin = -1
        , xmax = 1
        , ymin = -1
        , ymax = 1
        %, x dir = reverse
        , view={-40}{30}]
   \addplot3
   [
    surf
   ,  faceted color=blue
   , samples  = 15
   , domain   = -1:1
   , y domain = -1:1
   ]
    {56+ 1* x + 2* y + 3*x*y};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marco for your answer. Could you help me how to put comma (,) after Temp and before N. Thanks

Comment: put the value of `xlabel` into brackets: `xlabel = {Temp, $N$ \newline Slice at X}`. This normally recommended for all values which contains spaces or other symbols like your comma.