# PGFPlots - How to make multiline axis labels with non-boxed axis

Tags: pgfplots

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16218/168657) describes how to create multiline axis labels for boxed axes. However, when I try to do this with non-boxed axes it fails. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  title=MWE,
  xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel={some\\x\\label},
  ylabel style={align=center}, ylabel={some\\y\\label},
  axis x line=middle,
  % axis y line=middle,
  xtick=\empty,
  ytick=\empty,
]
  \addplot[
    samples=100,
    domain=-2:2,
  ] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces
[image]

How can I get the x-axis label to also span 3 lines?

I'm aware that the question linked above also discusses the use of `text width` as a possible solution. However, replacing `xlabel style=...` in my example with `xlabel style={align=center, text width=2cm}` does not change the result.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115026/pgfplots-splitting-xlabel-on-two-lines

Comment: @jsbibra that question asks about boxed axes, which is the same as the question I linked. But, this question asks specifically about non-boxed axes. I'm aware of the two methods mentioned in both links (`align` and `text width`) but they don't have an effect here when used in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" with your code is that you change `axis x line` **after** you have changed the `xlabel style` and thus *your* change is overwritten. So just change the `axis x line` first and you'll receive the result you expect.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    title=MWE,
    axis x line=middle,     % <-- moved up
    xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel={some\\x\\label},
    ylabel style={align=center}, ylabel={some\\y\\label},
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
]
  \addplot[
    samples=100,
    domain=-2:2,
  ] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 0):

`xlabel` is printed as node. So you can set a specific text width. This allows line breaks. The modification can be done by the option `xlabel style`. An example is shown in the documentation on page 173:

```
xlabel style={align=right,text width=3cm}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title=MWE,
    xlabel style= xlabel style={align=left,text width=2cm},{align=center}, xlabel={some\\x\\label},
    ylabel style={align=center}, ylabel={some\\y\\label},
    axis x line=middle,
    % axis y line=middle,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot[
    samples=100,
    domain=-2:2,
    ] {x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

As long as the `xaxis` and `yaxis` are at the default pos that is bottom and left respectively the multiline is obeyed for the axis labels but if the `yaxis` or `xaxis` is moved to the center/middle the multiline environ does not behave and we get a single line axis label

In the example below moving the `yaxis` to middle but leaving the `xaxis` at default bottom pos-- here the `xaxis` retains multiline environ but not so for the `yaxis`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel style={
                                align=left,
                                text width=3cm
                                },
                xlabel=A quite long label with a line break,
                title=MWE,
%               xlabel style={
%                               align=center,
%                               text width=1cm
%                               },
%               {align=center}, 
%               xlabel={some x label},
                ylabel style={align=center}, 
                ylabel={some\\y\\label},
%               axis x line=middle,
                 axis y line=middle,
%               xtick=\empty,
%               ytick=\empty,
                ]
    \addplot[
    samples=100,
    domain=-2:2,
    ] {x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now if `xaxis` also moves to the middle the multiline here also is not obeyed

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel style={
                                align=left,
                                text width=3cm
                                },
                xlabel=A quite long label with a line break,
                title=MWE,
%               xlabel style={
%                               align=center,
%                               text width=1cm
%                               },
%               {align=center}, 
%               xlabel={some x label},
                ylabel style={align=center}, 
                ylabel={some\\y\\label},
                axis x line=middle,
                 axis y line=middle,
%               xtick=\empty,
%               ytick=\empty,
                ]
    \addplot[
    samples=100,
    domain=-2:2,
    ] {x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Probably one of the legends will clarify**

Comment: It appears that just the `{align=center}` part has an effect. I'm not noticing any effect from `xlabel style`. In particular, I don't notice any effect from adding `text width` to my original example. I think maybe this analysis is a false positive. Do you know why `align=center` outside of `xlabel style` produces the desired result?